# Property 'touched' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'

Tags: html, angular

```
<input id="fileTitleVar" type="text" #fileTitleVar>
 <span *ngIf="fileTitleVar.touched && fileTitleVar.blurred">
        Input has been touched
      </span>
```

Property 'touched' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'
Property 'blurred' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'

When I compile my angular application with "*fullTemplateTypeCheck*" option true then I am able to see these errors.

To Reproduce this issue Create a angular application.

```
in "*tsconfig.app.json*" file update below code
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
  }
```

and use above code inside app.component.html file.
When we run ng serve command it will throw above mentioned errors.

```
 <input id="fileTitleVar" type="text" #fileTitleVar>
 <span *ngIf="fileTitleVar.touched && fileTitleVar.blurred">
        Input has been touched
      </span>
```

Error should not come as it is running when I remove enableIvy and fullTemplateTypeCheck attributes from "tsconfig.app.json" file.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use ngModel directive to make touched flag available :

```
 <input id="fileTitleVar" type="text" ngModel #fileTitleVar="ngModel">
 <span *ngIf="fileTitleVar.touched">
        Input has been touched
 </span>
```

As I remeber blurred doesn't exists on ngModel directive, you can add `[ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"` instead :

```
<input id="fileTitleVar" type="text" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" #fileTitleVar="ngModel">
     <span *ngIf="fileTitleVar.touched">
            Input has been touched
     </span>
```

also don't forget to import FormsModule to make ngModel directive available.